# How to return different output formats from the same controller method in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I want to set up the proper routes and models so when I visit www.myapp.com/search?keyword=test I get a view with data and when I visit api.myapp.com/search?keyword=test I get JSON representation of the exact same search result.

If I sort out the subdomain routes like so:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.myapp.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function($subdomain)
    {
        dd($subdomain);
    });
});
```

What's the simplest way to use the same model method but instead of returning a view (for non-subdomain routes) with the array of model objects like so:

```
return view('search', compact('models'));
```

I'd return an array of JSON objects, simply like so:

```
return $models;
```

Note: a subdomain is not that necessary, it can also be myapp.com/api/search?keyword=test

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way to do this.

---

One option is to not use a separate subdomain or path at all. Instead, use the built-in mechanism to check which `Content-Type`s are in the `Accept` header of the request.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function getSearch(Request $req)
    {
        $keyword = $req->input('keyword');

        $results = yourCodeThatDoesTheSearch();

        // If the request has header `Accept: */json`, return JSON
        if ($req->wantsJson())
        {
            return $results;
        }

        // Otherwise, return view
        return view('search', compact('results'));
    }
}
```

---

However, you may still wish to do it with a subdomain, either because you can't control the request headers, or because you want to have an easy indicator of what response you will get.

Here's the easiest way to do it with a subdomain:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function getSearch(Request $req)
    {
        $keyword = $req->input('keyword');

        $results = yourCodeThatDoesTheSearch();

        // If the request came to the API subdomain, return JSON
        if ($req->route('subdomain') === 'api')
        {
            return $results;
        }

        // Otherwise, return view
        return view('search', compact('results'));
    }
}
```

---

However, if you plan to do this in many places in your code, you should avoid repeating the same `if` statement everywhere.

Instead, create yourself a helper function:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory;

if (! function_exists('response_auto')) {
    function response_auto($view, $data, $request, $status = 200, array $headers = [])
    {
        $factory = app(ResponseFactory::class);

        if ($request->wantsJson())
        {
            return $factory->json($data, $status, $headers);
        }


        return $factory->view($view, compact('data'), $status, $headers);
    }
}
```

You can then use it in your controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function getSearch(Request $req)
    {
        $keyword = $req->input('keyword');

        $results = yourCodeThatDoesTheSearch();

        return response_auto('search', $results, $req);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Moshe Katz answer. If you just perform a `$req->wantsJson()` in your controller, works fine. However, there are occasions where if the user hits the back button, json will be returned in the view due to caching. A robust api would be in it's own controllers and use a repository for your db queries. That may be overkill.

Another option is to use a query parameter in your url.

Example:
*in your ajax client (axios)*

```
axios.get('/stuff', {params: {json: true}).then(response => return response);
```

*this will send a request to*

```
/stuff?json=true
```

*in your laravel controller (StuffController@index)*

```
public function index(Request $request) 
{ 
    $stuff = Stuff::all();

    if ($request->query('json')) { 
        return $stuff; 
    }

    return view('stuff.index', compact('stuff'));
}
```

This allows you to easily identify if the request wants json, prevents unwanted returns due to browser caching and keep the code in the same controller.